# Store data in child process C program

Tags: c

I want to create a program that count the occurrence of caracters in text , for that i want my program to work with parent/child process communication , the idea is simple i want the parent to read the stdin send the caracters to child who will count and return the result.

I want to return the result after reading the whole text , then the parent will display the result like this :
For a text like this "AaaaA" i get:

- 'a' is displayed 3 times
- 'A' is displayed 2 times

To do my task i used for and 2 pipes here is the sample of my code :

---

```
// I'll skip the code for variable and file input because i have a specific question.
.......
 // basic code

if( pid_child == 0){

 // child code

    close(pipe_1[1]);
    close(pipe_2[0]);

    read(pipe_1[0], &caract, sizeof(char));

}else {
   // parent area
    while((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF){
        if((c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')){

             close(pipe_1[0]);
             close(pipe_2[1]);

             write(pipe_1[1], &c, sizeof(char));
        } 
    }
 }
```

I know that when you `fork()` a parent process you create a copy of this process , and i want to know how do i store all the result in child process then i would read them or call them at the end of reading my file ?

For instance i want to create a 2D dynamic array that can hold all the  caracters if the first dimension and the number of occurence on the second dimension .

For the previous exemple i would

`int **array;
 array = malloc(2 * sizeof(int *));`

and it would give me :

A 2

a 3

I know how to communicate between child and parent back and fourth but
my problem is i want absolutely to call the final product of this array after reading all my text so the parent can't have the result before that ?

Is there a way to do it, i don't know if it's correct but i want that array to act like a local variable in the child process and i want to update it everytime i get the same or new  caracters?

Thank you

Comment: if you want to know when to send the data back from the child process, you could send it back the moment you receive EOF from the parent process. this means that `read()` returns -1. Test for this and return the data through pipe.

Comment: But how do i store the data and update it while im in my loop of reading

Comment: fork creates two processes and so they will execute concurrently. you send the data from the child process only when it has finished being processed (this implies that the while loop has terminated) and you can retrieve the data in parent process after the while.

Comment: So just to make it clear , because im learning c , First i fork to create the child , the parent will read the stdin, it  will read the first caracter wich is  A and send it to the child the child will store A in his array then go back to the parent then the parent will send the next one and we do that untill the end, but does that mean the child must be looped too ?

Comment: precisely, the child should loop until `EOF` or until say `\n` which would be easier. so the moment you hit enter, the loop ends and the child process receives all that..the parent will only send data when the ENTER key is pressed so if you haven't pressed enter, the child will keep waiting for data. you could use a `select()` in a loop to see if there is any data to be read from the pipe. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html

Comment: and before i forget, `select()` blocks so you won't need a while in child process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if( pid_child == 0){

 // child code

    close(pipe_1[1]);
    close(pipe_2[0]);
    fd_set inputfd;
    FD_ZERO(inputfd);  // zero out fd set
    FD_SET(pipe_1[0], &inputfd);  // add input pipe to set
    int state = select(pipe_1[0] + 1, &inputfd, NULL, NULL, NULL); // wait until input arrives
    if( FD_ISSET(pipe_1[0], &inputfd) )
    { read(pipe_1[0], &caract, sizeof(char)); }
    // process it and send it back
}else {
   // parent area
    // you could also do a select before sending the data - for stdin - see link 
    while((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF){
        if((c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')){

             close(pipe_1[0]);
             close(pipe_2[1]);

             write(pipe_1[1], &c, sizeof(char));
        } 
    }
    // do a select here as well and wait for input to come from the user
    fd_set child_input;
    FD_ZERO(child_input);
    FD_SET(pipe_1[1], &child_input);   // i'm assuming pipe_1[1] is input pipe
    select(pipe_1[1] + 1, &child_input, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if( FD_ISSET(pipe_1[1], &child_input) )
          // child has sent back data, process it
 }
```

-- select example: https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/multi/advanced.html#select